# Web service optimization

Tags: c#, web-services

I have Webservice Project.
in that I have one ".asmx" file.
in file I have around 200+ methods.

so what to do to make it optimised ?

Which type of Coding Structure can be used for optimise ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need to optimise in terms of performance? Or in terms of your code being a mess?

**Firstly**, is your business logic in the methods themselves? If so this might have become a mess.

I have a very large web-service which I manage. I have split refactored out all key behavour into backing classes, so that the ASMX file itself is not unwieldy.

**Secondly** consider breaking your asmx file up into several partial classes, it won't help performance but it should make your system easier to manage. I'd guess that with 200 methods there are some key groups of functionality that can be separated out.

**However**
If performance is your issue, you will need to provide us with more information on what your service actually does, in order for us to provide more detail.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for reply..
I have divided all methods by it function in Partial Classes.
but My Main Aim to ask que. is that When I make object of web service class then it will slow to load 200+ Methods.

So What type of Code structure I Should Use By that class load performance get fast.